# Trying to make an LC3 binary code that checks if 2 numbers are equal

Tags: lc3

I am trying to make a machine instruction program that asks for two user inputs(single digit) and then checks that two numbers are the same. Then it stores the first user input into the Register R3, and the second user input into R4. If two numbers are the same, the R5 will be set 1. Otherwise, R5 is 0. Finally, print out the check result R5(The printing result is Optional).

Comment: Ok, not too difficult, but there's a few things going on there.  You need input (easy), compare (have to subtract on a machine that doesn't have subtraction), and an if-then-else (straightforward).  As this is a Q&A site, you should ask a question about where you want to focus.  Make it a technical question, b/c "can someone help?" is off topic here.

Comment: @ErikEidt. Thank you for your insight. To be honest, my teacher just gave us this assignment without any practice whatsoever with this language. I've been trying to teach myself with what little info I have found on the internet, and have been able to successfully code the input. This is what I have so far.                                        
 .ORIG x3000

IN ;get 1st input
ADD R3, R0, #0
OUT
IN ;get 2nd input ;
ADD R4, R0, #0
OUT

.end         I understand what needs to be done and I'd easily be able to code this python, but I don't know assembly language.

Comment: Ok, there's no compare so subtract instead and check for the result being zero.  Oh, there's no subtract either, so negate one of them and add instead.  Oh, there's no negation, so not followed by adding 1.  Do all that and you can see if the values are the same or not.

Comment: @ErikEidt okay cool thank you! That helps. But what do you mean by "so not followed by adding 1"

Comment: LC-3 only has 3 logical operations: ADD, NOT, AND.  To negate you'll need to use the NOT operation and an add of 1 -- this is the definition of negation using 2's complement representation of signed numbers.